# SLRequest get image Headers(width and height) without downloading

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, slrequest

i am creating cells with width and height of UIImage.
i am getting the images from Facebook post OR twitter Feed.

Currently i just can set the cells size **AFTER** downloading the image and this leads to delaying.

So my question is: is it possible to get the image headers **WITHOUT** downloading the image itself with folling Frameworks/SDKs:

- **SLRequest**
- **Facebook SDK**
- **Twitter Api**

i only need the header informations of the images for layouting my UI.
Any recommendations or experiences about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the information you want is returned in the header then you could try:

1. Get an `NSURLRequest` request with `preparedURLRequest`
2. Make a `mutableCopy` of it
3. Call `setHTTPMethod:` with `@"HEAD"` to specify you only want headers

Note that if the server doesn't support HEAD requests then the image data would generally be returned anyway (usually instead of an error)...

Comment: but this will also force a download(which make everything slower) before getting the header infos, or not?